# New line after going into folder terminal

Tags: ubuntu, shell, zsh

After I downloaded zsh and tried to go into a folder zsh always puts an enter after the name of the folder. Is there anyway I can fix this?

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at your `.zshrc`, you will see a line `prompt adam1` which defines how your prompt is composed.

The definition of the `adam1` is in the `/usr/share/zsh/functions/Prompts/prompt_adam1_setup`. A look at this file confirms it is rather complex : it measures the prompt length and compare to 40. If the prompt is too large, a newline is inserted before the `%`.

The command `prompt -l` displays the alternative themes. Then you can pick one of them and type for example `prompt fire`. When you are happy with an alternative, you can edit the `.zshrc` and change your future default theme. `redhat` and `suse` are some examples of single line prompts.